# Trying to understand xsl:key

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to xslt and I am trying to learn xslt 1.0.

I am trying to figure out how I can obtain the following result with my xml file.  I played around a lot with my xsl file but I think there is something I just don't get because it's not working at all ...

Please keep your answer simple as I am a beginner. Thank you !

The result should look like this :

```
Code      Number of students    Average per course
INF4830     3                   86.0
INF1130     3                   77.7
INF1330     4                   82.0
INF4930     1                   40.0
```

This is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="temptransfo.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<university>
<student><name>Robert Shaw</name>
<course code="INF4830" note="90" />
<course code="INF1130" note="70" />
<course code="INF1330" note="76" /></student>
<student><name>Peter Manning</name>
<course code="INF4830" note="76" />
<course code="INF1130" note="73" />
<course code="INF1330" note="74" /></student>
<student><name>Jeff Cooper</name>
<course code="INF4930" note="40" />
<course code="INF1130" note="90" />
<course code="INF1330" note="80" /></student>
<student><name>Laureen Hanley</name>
<course code="INF4830" note="92" />
<course code="INF1330" note="98" /></student>
</university>
```

So far, this is my xsl file but it's not working.  None of the results show up in the table ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output 
    method="html"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    indent="yes" ></xsl:output>

<xsl:key name="mytable" match="student", use="course" />  
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<caption>Test1</caption>
<tr>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Number of student</th>
<th>Course average</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select = "//course" >
<xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('mytable',course[@code])[1])">
<tr>
<td> <xsl:value-of select="@code"/> </td>
<td> <xsl:value-of select="count(//course[@code=current()/@code])"/> </td>
<td> <xsl:value-of select="(sum (//course/@note)) div (count(//course[@code]))"/> </td>
</tr>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Apart from the conceptual mistakes I pointed out in my answer, you also have a syntax error: you cannot have a comma in-between attributes (in line 10 of your XSLT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to get a list of distinct courses; for this, you need to make your key:

```
<xsl:key name="course-by-code" match="course" use="@code" />
```

Next, you want to re-use the key in order to get the list of all enrollments in each course - something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/university/student/course[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('course-by-code', @code)[1])]" >
    <xsl:variable name="enrollments" select="key('course-by-code', @code)"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($enrollments)"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($enrollments/@note) div count($enrollments)"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I now have a much better understanding of how to work with xsl:key.  In my head it was a lot more complicated than that but your explanations made it a lot easier for me to understand.  Thanks a lot ! :-)  I am new to xslt and I get confused easily, I find it's not always easy to understand.